# Cannot play video file from external hard drive on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, codec

I have upgraded my OS from 8.1 to 10 and I have this weird problem that if I open a video file from my external hard drive it doesn't play but when I copy the same file to my desktop it works fine. I think this is some kind of permission problem [the file is not read-only and I have already tried to open the player as admin]. Does anyone have any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Does it play using a different video player, like for instance VLC?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister No I've tried with different players